# How do I get rid of "thread1: signal SIGABRT"?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a camera app.

When I try to run I get this thread:

> thread1: signal SIGABRT

in the following code.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {}
```

This is only the viewcontroller class I use:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {



@IBAction func takePicture(sender: UIButton) {
    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera)) {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {})
        } else {
            print("Rear camera doesn't exist")
        }
    } else {
        print("Camera inaccessable")
    }
}




@IBOutlet weak var currentImage: UIImageView!

let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    print("Got an image")
    if let pickedImage:UIImage = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]) as? UIImage {
        let selectorToCall = Selector("imageWasSavedSuccessfully:didFinishSavingWithError:context:")
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, self, selectorToCall, nil)
    }
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        // Anything you want to happen when the user saves an image
    })
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("User canceled image")
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        // Anything you want to happen when the user selects cancel
    })
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: You have to initialize UI objects with "real" initializers. The default initializer `()` has no effect.

Comment: Are you getting this error after you've clicked / done something or immediately? Have you checked your connections with `currentImage`?